# Unique Identifier for Mouse,Keyboard and other HID devices

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, usb, mouse

I have an MFC application that used to find the details of devices in the windows. The PnPID of USB Storage devices is unique in every system. but in the case of mouse-keyboard, the PnPID is different on every computer for the same device. is there is any way to find the unique identifier of Mouse, Keyboard, and HID using C++. If anyone knows about the unique identifier for HID devices or mouse and keyboard please share.Here is my code.

```
while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,lCount++,&DevInfoData))
        {
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            DWORD   dwDataTypeHardwareid;
            LPTSTR  pszBufferHardwareid     = NULL;
            LPTSTR  pszBufferPnPid      = NULL;
            DWORD   dwBuffSizeHardwareid    = 0; 
            int     iRetValHardwareid       = 1;
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            iRetValHardwareid = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DevInfoData, SPDRP_HARDWAREID, &dwDataTypeHardwareid, (PBYTE)pszBufferHardwareid, dwBuffSizeHardwareid, &dwBuffSizeHardwareid);
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();

            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            {
                if (pszBufferHardwareid) 
                    LocalFree(pszBufferHardwareid);
                //// / //
                pszBufferHardwareid = (char *)LocalAlloc(LPTR,dwBuffSizeHardwareid * 2);
                iRetValHardwareid=SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DevInfoData, SPDRP_HARDWAREID, &dwDataTypeHardwareid, (PBYTE)pszBufferHardwareid, dwBuffSizeHardwareid, &dwBuffSizeHardwareid);
            }       
            if(StrStrI(pszBufferHardwareid,"HID\\"))
            {
                if(StrStrI(pszBufferClass,"Mouse"))
                {
                    CM_Get_Device_ID(DevInfoData.DevInst, pszBufferPnPid, MAX_PATH, 0); //**Not unique in different machines**
                    CString strDevid = (CString)pszBufferPnPid;
                    strDevid.Trim();
                    strDevid.MakeUpper();
                    SaveDeviceDetails(strDevid); //Method to save device details to DB
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The VID:PID combination should be remain the same for one particular device, irregardless from the PC. However, what is your goal exactly? Do you need an unique identifier per deice (meaning, even if you buy two identical keyboard, they should have a different ID) or you just want to distinguish between models?

Comment: @S.Monteleone. If I bought 2 identical keyboards there is any unique identifier distinguish that 2 keyboard.

Comment: In general, nope. You may look for the device serial number, if reported, but there is no guarantee that it will be uinique.

Comment: It's indeed well-known that cheap manufacturers do not bother with programming individual serials into keyboards and mice. Normal users really don't care about that, and it can easily add many cents to the production cost.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP clarified he's looking for an unique identifier for HID devices, I suggest to try with the device serial number, although there is no guarantee that it will be unique.

On Win32 you can use the [HidD_GetSerialNumberString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getserialnumberstring) function to retrieve the serial number of an HID device.